ValueError: Invalid classes inferred from unique values of `y`. Expected: [0 1 2], got ['Dropout' 'Enrolled' 'Graduate']
I'm working on a classification task using the XGBoost classifier model. My dataset contains categorical variables, my target classes ('Dropout', 'Enrolled', 'Graduate').
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

xgb = XGBClassifier(
    n_estimators=200,
    max_depth=6,  
    learning_rate=0.1,  
    subsample=0.8,
    colsample_bytree=0.8,
    eval_metric='mlogloss'  
)

xgb.fit(X_train, y_train)

I get the following error
ValueError: Invalid classes inferred from unique values of `y`. Expected: [0 1 2], 
got ['Dropout' 'Enrolled' 'Graduate']

After that, I'm using label encoder techniques; it works fine. But I need ['Dropout' 'Enrolled' 'Graduate'] this categorical in the production section. How I can change this  [0 1 2] to ['Dropout' 'Enrolled' 'Graduate'] after the train XGBClassifier.

Classes need to be integers, not strings.

You can restore true labels from encoded output, check here for example

LabelEncoder can not only transorm your original target into numerical values but also it can inverse_transform numerical values into your original target values.
So your code should look like this:
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit_transform(y_train)


# fit
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

xgb = XGBClassifier(
    n_estimators=200,
    max_depth=6,  
    learning_rate=0.1,  
    subsample=0.8,
    colsample_bytree=0.8,
    eval_metric='mlogloss'  
)

xgb.fit(X_train, y_train)



# prediction
pred = xgb.predict(X_test)
original_pred = le.inverse_transform(pred)

Official documentation here.
